# how to get local timezone on azure service

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-web-app-service

I have a service running on azure cloud. This service runs in every 1 min and picks some files from ftp server. These files have Datetime fields and not datetimeoffset, which when read by service become UTC dates. These FTp servers are in different timezone.

For example one of the ftp is in GMT timezone. Say file has date 12/5/2015 time 12:15. This is read by service as UTC(because no timezone received) and stored in database as 12/5/2015: 12:15:00 +0:00, while it should be 
12/5/2015: 11:15:00 +0:00.

I still want to save date in database as UTC, need a way to get these ftp timezones, so I can parse date correctly.

The problem is we can't make any changes in file.
Is there any way cloud sevice can get timezone for these FTP?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing Azure specific here for what you want, but you can roll your own solution.

You'd have to do some fancy stuff to guess the timezone of an FTP server, which would involve doing a DNS lookup of the server to figure out it's IP address, mapping that IP address to a city, and looking up the city's Time Zone.  You could do that but it would be error prone.

There's an easier and more reliable option. It sounds like you your list of FTP servers is fairly static. You can just create a lookup table that says which timezone each FTP server is in, and use that table to figure out which timezone offset you should use.

Answer (score 0):

**Best practice:** Server-side code should never depend on the time zone or culture settings of the server that is hosting the code.  Instead, these concerns should be addressed in the code itself.

For example, assuming your service is written in C# / .NET, you might have code like this:

```csharp
string s = "12/5/2015 12:15 PM";  // from the file
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
DateTime utc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
```

The above code relies on the server's local time zone during the `ToUniversalTime` function.  It also relies on the server's culture during the `Parse` function.

Instead, you should have knowledge of the time zone and culture of the input file.  For example:

```csharp
string s = "12/5/2015 12:15 PM";  // from the file
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
```

This code supplies the CET/CEST time zone, and also provides an exact input format using the invariant culture.

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById will fail if your service is hosted on a platform other than windows.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО - This question was asked and answered well before .NET Core was released.  You are correct with regard to modern .NET.  One can either use an equivalent IANA time zone ID (such as `Europe/Budapest`), or one can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library which will let you use either form of time zone on any supported platform.

Comment: Awesome @Matt, I experience the issue first hand then landed on this question and commented without checking the dates. I was going to use NodaTime though but it seems your lib specificly  addresses this very problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Late post, but thought I would post my solution to help anyone else:

```
 TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

 var cetZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.StandardName);
 var cetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, cetZone);

 DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(cetTime.ToString());
```

In my instance, the localZone.StandardName gives me "South African Standard Time", which I believe is GMT+2.

Hope this helps someone else out!

Cheers

Comment: `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` is obsolete now. Use `TimeZone.Local` instead. And `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` doesn't accept `TimeZone.StandardName`, but `TimeZone.Id`.

Comment: Thanks for this info, much appreciated.